# Making a static/sticky menu bar with CSS

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I am trying to get my navigation/menu bar to "stick" to the top of the page even as the reader scrolls down. I've tried both position: fixed; and position: absolute;, but it hasn't been working and I'm not sure why. I'll include the code below:

**CSS**

```
 /* Navigation */

    div.menu {
        width:100%;
        height:40px;
        display:block;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        right:0;
    }
    div.menu ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-size: .8em;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 40%;
    }
    div.menu li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    div.menu li a{
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1.5em;
    }
    div.menu li a:hover {
        background-color: #6b9d68;
        color: white;
    }
    div.menu li a.active {
        background-color: #000000;
        color: white;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="cv.php">CV</a></li>
        <li><a href="research.php">Research</a></li>
        <li><a href="teaching.php">Teaching</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://academia-25-to-life.blogspot.com">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="divider">
        <img src="divider.jpg">
    </div>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: First, your code is in ´<head>´ - it should be in ´<body>´. I copied your code and it worked for me. Are you sure, you include the css within your html? In the example above you don't.

Comment: ....Somehow I knew it'd be something dumb like that. You're right. I didn't put it in the body. All fixed. Thanks!

Comment: no problem - i will add an answer, please mark it as correct answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do you declare it inline or in two separate files? If the latter you are missing stylesheet reference.

Also, usage of `<nav>` tag for clarity is advised - http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position:sticky;` on your element but I highly advise against it since it's only supported by safari.

You need Javascript to do this, essentially you listen to the scroll event and when you've reached a certain scroll position, you switch your position to `position:fixed`

If you need some help I would suggest you check out this tutorial http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-sticky-navigation

Comment: maybe this link is more complete :)  http://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/

Answer (score 0):

The easey method you should use JS (JQuery) 
Also can try CSS:

```
#navigation {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}

#header {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Or

```
.nav 
{
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This one is for safari bit experimental.

Comment: The original poster (op) no longer has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the code between the `<body>`-tag and include the css code within your html file.